# xcodebuild hangs on Xcode 11 beta, succeeds on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild

As the name of this post implies, I'm facing build-system issues with the Xcode 11 Beta. I worked since June on an update to my app, but only just recently attemped to archive it for TestFlight. Upon doing so, I found an issue where the archive never succeeds, but it also never fails. Instead it indefinitely hangs, never throwing an error or any hints as to why it's not conntinuing.

I've been able to isolate this issue to Xcode 11, as the identical codebase archives without a hitch in Xcode 10 (latest version as of writing).

I've submitted a radar with number FB7172492.

While I wait for a response to my radar, does any one here have any tricks as how I could either a) Get it to archive, or b) Get it to tell me what its stuck on.

It's worth noting, the build hang only occurs for the Release builds, any Debug build builds and runs without a problem.

### `xcodebuild`

When I run `xcodebuild` in the terminal, like Xcode it hangs, and its file logs look like this:

```
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.57]: ▸ [35m2019-09-02 16:39:07.577 xcodebuild[20349:464120] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfe8cbc1a0), Will’s iPhone, iPhone, 13.1 (17A5821e), 00008020-001131943A04002E> == Underlying device preparation errors ==[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.57]: ▸ [35m2019-09-02 16:39:07.577 xcodebuild[20349:464120] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfe8cbc1a0), Will’s iPhone, iPhone, 13.1 (17A5821e), 00008020-001131943A04002E> -- Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.57]: ▸ [35mDomain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.58]: ▸ [35mCode: 5[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.58]: ▸ [35mFailure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7fbfe8a3f120:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fbfe8a3ef90:'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.58]: ▸ [35m--[0m
INFO [2019-09-02 16:39:07.58]: ▸ [35m2019-09-02 16:39:07.577 xcodebuild[20349:464120] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfe8cbc1a0), Will’s iPhone, iPhone, 13.1 (17A5821e), 00008020-001131943A04002E> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==[0m
```

It says can't connect to my device, but it really shouldn't be trying to do that, since I'm just building, not installing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug; you should report it to Apple.

Comment: I have submitted a radar

Comment: @Will I don't know if this works or not but it's worth giving a try. copy xcodebuild from stable version and paste to the beta version then try to build. you can find the file at Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild

Comment: @Will, don't know if it could be related to, but you can try setting the workspace setting to build with Legacy, just an idea at this point really, since you're facing this issue

Comment: Can you show us the xcodebuild directive?

From what is above it looks like you are setting a specific destination. Can you build for archiving using the Release path?

Comment: I`m having the same issue, did you find a workaround to get your project to build on XCode 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with a framework called `SwiftSoup`, the library has been patched and archiving succeeds.